# Evaluate expression using lists maxima

Tags: list, maxima

I'd like the result of the below maxima input to be [6,12,18] but it results in 2ac. Can anyone help?

```
a:2;
c:[1,2,3];
b:'(a*c);
''b;
a:3;
''b;
f:'(b*2);
''f;
```

Comment: minor edit made. 12ac to 2ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ev(f, infeval)` is what you want. See `? ev` for info about `infeval` and other evaluation flags.

```
(%i1) c : [1, 2, 3];
(%o1)                              [1, 2, 3]
(%i2) b : '(a*c);
(%o2)                                 a c
(%i3) a : 3;
(%o3)                                  3
(%i4) f : '(b*2);
(%o4)                                 2 b
(%i5) f;
(%o5)                                 2 b
(%i6) ''f;
(%o6)                                2 a c
(%i7) ev (f);
(%o7)                                2 a c
(%i8) ev (f, infeval);
(%o8)                             [6, 12, 18]
```

You can also write `ev(f, infeval);` as just `f, infeval;` at the input prompt.

That said, my advice is, don't try too hard to find tricky ways to evaluate stuff. It's easy to write something which has unexpected results and hard to understand. You'll have to find a balance between trying to get Maxima to do what your want, and accommodating Maxima's idiosyncrasies (i.e. changing your ideas to match Maxima's).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `f:'(''b*2);`. This works as you expect.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other alternative to adding '' to each variable that I need to be evaluated?

Comment: @TomH I don't know if it exists. And don't forget to upvote, please.